# SSRS Exporting to CSV format

Tags: excel, csv, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

When I export my information to CSV file so its in raw data format and easily used in one of the fields I have a number that is big (for example, 140313055811).  It's really just an invoice number, but when I export it to CSV and open it, it shows something like 1.41E+11.  I need to get it to display the full number instead of this.  Is there a way? I tried making the textbox that its in as a number, I tried make the value area of the field =int(name of field), I tried changing it to text.  None of these do the trick.

The only one that has worked is =FormatNumber(fieldname) and while this did work, it put commas in between as if it were a large number (this is an invoice number).  So I was thinking I could use the =Format function but when it asks for "style as string" in the expression what do I put?

I need this report to be automated on the enterprise sharepoint site that's why I am going through great lengths to try to get it to automatically come out right.

Exporting it to excel form makes it hard to use the data, the CSV form is the best way to manipulate the data.

Thanks for any help, I appreciate it

Comment: Have you opened the CSV with a text editor to be sure that the "1.41E+11" isn't just Excel being Excel?

Comment: It is excel changing the format, but with the date ranges it doesn't and this has never happened in the past.  I'd rather it show me the ######### where it is saying that the column is too small than changing the format of the invoice #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the CSV file in notepad, you might find the value as a scientific number before even making it to the excel.

You can stick spaces in front and/or behind the value to make the CSV file correct (and treat it as text), but excel will simply make it scientific again anyway the moment its opened and sees numbers.

The only solution I know of where the export ultimately is used in excel, is to stick a real character into the string like "INV: " before the value and deal with it in the excel file.

```
= "INV: " & Fields!invoicenumber.Value
```

so it reads    "INV: 1230412893481239435"   as text.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the IIF condition and checking which format you are exporting to - Something like:

=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL" or Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "CSV", "=""" + Fields!FieldName.Value + """", Fields!FieldName.Value)

You can then add an = and double quotes around the field value as shown.  This will force Excel to render it as text without having to put a label around it.